# Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 2015 modules

Tags: angular, typescript, clipboard

I'm trying to use the follwing line:

```
import Clipboard = require('clipboard');
```

and I get the following error:

```
   [default] c:\xampp\htdocs\isitperfect\node_modules\angular2-clipboard\src\clipboard.directive.ts:2:0 
Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 2015 modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.
```

The error is in this line:

```
import Clipboard = require('clipboard');
```

I tried:

```
import * as Clipboard from 'clipboard';
```

and some other variations but couldn't figure out how to fix it.

I'm using typescript 2.0.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 54):

I was facing the same issue as you.

In the **tsconfig.json** file I replaced:

```
"module": "es6"
```

with

```
"module": "commonjs"
```

and restarted the terminal. It worked.

Comment: worked, but in my `tsconfig.app.json` file instead of `tsconfig.json`

Comment: ^^^ tsconfig.app.json was the fix for me too.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem and changing to:

```
import * as myGlobals from "../globals";
```

fixed the problem. `globals.ts` file is in the main `app` folder, and I'm loading it up from subfolder `services`.

Comment: This is not the same case

Comment: I know that's not the same case but I found your post because I had exactly the same error as you. And fixed that using line of code that I gave you with syntax: import * as "name" from "path". Hoped that might help you.

Comment: Example: import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';

Answer (score 6):

In case you are using Angular CLI: I was able to compile my project after I had set the value of `module` to `es2016` in the file `src/tsconfig.app.json`.

Comment: es2016 does not seem to be a valid value for the module field. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: it's `lib`, and not `module`

Comment: TypeScript gave me into trouble for using `es2016` as the module setting, but suggested `esnext` as an alternative and now it is happy.

Answer (score 2):

I used `default` member of imported function.

```
import {default as Clipboard} from 'clipboard';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set module as commonjs in tsconfig

You can try this example using webpack [here](https://github.com/maxisam/angular2-clipboard/tree/master/demo/webpack)

Comment: disclaimer: I don't maintain the webpack solution anymore. But I have updated the broken link for you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating my vsCode.

just replace with `"module": "es5"`

to `"module": "commonjs"` in **tsconfig.app.json**

Answer (score 0):

Similar to KristianC, I got this warning for lodash on upgrade to Angular 11

```
const cloneDeep = require('lodash-es/cloneDeep');
```

"Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules."

Warning resolved on updating "require" to "import"

```
import { cloneDeep } from 'lodash-es';
```