# How to import in Angular (v6)

Tags: angular

How can I import the "geojson" package into my Angular 6 project?

I previously had the following in my Angular 5.2 project.

```
import GeoJson = require("geojson");
import WKT = require("terraformer-wkt-parser");
```

I've since upgraded to Angular 6 and now I get runtime error:

```
error TS1202: Import assignment cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript modules. Consider using 'import * as ns from "mod"', 'import {a} from "mod"', 'import d from "mod"', or another module format instead.
```

So I checked out this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39664068/import-assignment-cannot-be-used-when-targeting-ecmascript-2015-modules) .  That doesn't appear to work since the values now have certain values.

So I then tried:

```
import GeoJson from "geojson";
```

But I still get runtime error:

```
Module '"C:/Dev/MyProject/ClientApp/node_modules/@types/geojson/index"' has no default export.
```

EDIT: Reformatted so that import line stood out.

Comment: import * as GeoJson from 'path' ?

try that

Comment: I did: Let me reformat the SO better.

Comment: I'm sorry.  Yes that worked.

Comment: Sweet, great! woo woo

Comment: Add as an answer Taranjit so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

import * as GeoJson from 'path'

Answer (score 2):

With

```
import GeoJson from "geojson";
```

You are looking for a module with the name "GeoJson" this is only correct if you are importing an exported library as a module

As apparently, it is not the case, you must import all the contents of the library  (*) as if it were a module

```
import * as GeoJson from 'geojson'
```